# Converting a Swing database application to be web based

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, web

I have developed a swing application which connects to local MS Access Database on my computer. I want this application to be web-based, so that any person can just load the application using a given link.

I want my database to be present on my local computer only and want other clients changes to be automatically updated in it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial how to use Vaadin to build the web application, if you already have an existing Java Swing application: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+tutorial+for+Swing+developers

Answer (score 1):

[Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) will let you access your existing Swing app from a web page without any code changes. However, the app won't be ON the web page, but rather a download and auto-launch kind of thing.  If you've already done Swing development, then you may already be familiar with this since all of the Java tutorials have this.

For an example of how this works, see the [How to Use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) tutorial, and click the Launch button on the web page.

The app will be downloaded to the user's machine, but your Access database will reside on your local machine only.  The code will make the connection to read/write to your database (provided that your machine is turned on and a Connection can be made).

Answer (score 0):

AjaxSwing is a tool that provides a way to migrate from Java desktop applications to web applications at runtime, by providing automatic conversion to AJAX.

Demos : http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/demos.html

Download : http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/install/index.html

Link To YouTube Video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89bjXrU5BuA

You may also have a look at  Mia Transformer.

Website : http://www.mia-software.com

Comment: will it allow local database to run ??